# How do I allow users to import Youtube videos?

Tags: media, files

How do I allow users to import Youtube videos into their profile using the video URL?

I've no idea which module can do this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers. Research and testing needs to be done before asking a question. Please describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Install [media_youtube](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_youtube). Add a field to user profiles of this type.